# Pick a random number in a pool with duplicates in O(1) time and less than O(n) space?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory

Imagine trying to pick a random number from a pool of numbers that contains:

i1 times the number 1
i2 times the number 2
i3 times the number 3
... etc

For example picking a random number in a pool of
30 times the number 1
90 times the number 2
would yield 1 with 25% probability and 2 with 75% probability.

let NU be the number of unique numbers
let NT be the total number of numbers
In our example NU=2, NT=120.

Is there a way to achieve this in O(1) time and less than O(NT) space?

Edit: corrected probabilities in example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why is $1$ returned with probability $33\% < \frac{1}{3}$ and not with probability $\frac{30}{30+90} = \frac{1}{4}$?

Anyway, this can be done in $O(NU)$ space (assuming $i_1, \dots, i_{NU}$ each fit in $O(1)$ memory words) and $O(1)$ time (assuming you can sample an integer between $1$ and $\sum_{j=1}^{NU} i_j$ uniformly at random in $O(1)$ time) using the [alias method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_method).

The Wikipedia page includes a pseudocode that uses rational numbers (which might lead to a loss of precision, depending on their representation). If you are interested in a C++ implementation that uses integers, like in your description, see [here](https://bitbucket.org/steven_/motivo/src/default/src/common/random/AliasMethodSampler.h).

Comment: You were correct about the probabilities, I corrected that.
Fantastic thank you very much that's exactly what I was looking for. The alias method is quite brilliant really.